# Laravel 9 multiple middleware in route

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

I have this route, that should work for both middlewares

```
Route::middleware(['company', 'consultant'])->group(function () {
    Route::resource('/tasks', TaskController::class);
});
```

If I do

```
Route::middleware(['consultant'])->group(function () {
    Route::resource('/tasks', TaskController::class);
});
```

Or

```
Route::middleware(['company'])->group(function () {
    Route::resource('/tasks', TaskController::class);
});
```

Both work, yet the first example with both it does work just for the company.

In routeMiddleware I have as expected

```
'consultant' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsConsultant::class,
'company' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsCompany::class,
```

And in the Middleware folder

```
class IsCompany
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user() &&  Auth::user()->type == 2) {
             return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('dashboard')->with('error','You have not admin access');
    }
}

class IsConsultant
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user() &&  Auth::user()->type == 1) {
             return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('dashboard')->with('error','You have not admin access');
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, you can simply add the logic in the same middleware without the need of another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want both of the middleware to succeed and pass the request, they won't. They are mutually exclusive, since one needs `Auth::user()->type == 2` and other `Auth::user()->type == 1`

If one succeeds, the other has to fail by definition.

You can rather have a single middleware with `in_array(Auth::user()->type, [1, 2], true)` that'd work when the user type is either `1` or `2`, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I see, then I understood wrong how they work. I did not want to create another middleware, I thought the array would work for each of them.